# How to make a SELECT col1,col2 FROM table WHERE col1+" "+col2 LIKE "John D%"?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to select the name and lastname of all users which name+lastname starts with "John D", I mean it could select "John Doe", "John Deniro", "John Dalas".

but this select doesn't work:

```
SELECT name,lastname FROM users WHERE name+" "+lastname LIKE 'john D%';
```

So, how can I make that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You  could use `CONCAT`

```
SELECT name,lastname FROM users 
WHERE CONCAT(name , ' ', lastname) LIKE 'John D%';
```

or (better solution because conditions  will be [SARGable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799584/what-makes-a-sql-statement-sargable#799616)):

```
SELECT name,lastname FROM users 
WHERE name = 'John'
  and lastname LIKE 'D%'
```

Comment: Thanks, CONCAT is scallable and works for my real issue, where the lastname first letter could or could not be typed.

Answer (score 0):

You should split the parameters to get it working correctly.

```
SELECT `name`, `lastname`
FROM `users`
WHERE `name` LIKE "John%" AND `lastname` LIKE "D%"
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, if performance is vaguely important...

```
SELECT name
     , lastname 
  FROM users 
 WHERE name = 'John'
   AND lastname LIKE 'D%';
```